# Using pip to install application instead of packages

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way of using pip to install an application instead of packages?  I like how easy it is to update/install/remove python packages. But I'm wondering if it's the right tool for having users download a python app that runs out of $HOME/bin (or /usr/bin/) instead of installing it like a python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by application. But if your goal is to run a script without specifying it's precise location, then that's possible. You can do that in at least two ways:

1. After you install some app via pip, you can create links from your preferred `bin` directory to the entry point where the app is installed. For example link `/usr/bin/the_app` to `/opt/long/path/.venv/bin/the_app`.
2. Install in a common location which you add to your shell's `PATH`. If you don't necessarily care for full separation between apps, this can be easily achieved by installing them via `pip install --user the_app`, which will use some local path like `$HOME/.local/bin` or `$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin` or something else. (depending on your system)

Which way to go depends on whether this is a shared system, or you're the only user and some other constraints. Neither is wrong, but one may be more convenient.

For safety, I'd recommend solution 1. It's nice to have isolation between apps so dependencies don't conflict.

Comment: Ah, good point! I was wondering if pip was appropriate but I think your answer gives me a better approach. Thank you